# Spring Boot annotations: One PropertySource, many Properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm trying to achieve a setup where a single .properties file actually gets parsed into several Properties objects.

But no combination of variants (nested classes, qualifiers, etc) is actually yielding the same result.

Is this even possible? What's the recommended way of doing this?

Example below!

```
  // file: plugins.properties

  plugins.FooPlugin.enabled=true
  plugins.FooPlugin.amount=1
  plugins.BarPlugin.enabled=false
```

```java
  // file: (...)/foo/Properties.java

  @Configuration
  @Qualifier("Foo Plugin Properties")
  @PropertySource("classpath:plugins.properties")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "plugins.foo-plugin")
  public class FooPluginProperties {
    boolean enabled;
    Integer amount; 
  }

  // file: (...)/bar/Properties.java

  @Configuration
  @Qualifier("Bar Plugin Properties")
  @PropertySource("classpath:plugins.properties")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "plugins.bar-plugin")
  public class BarPluginProperties {
    boolean enabled;
  }
```

I may be getting a bit tangled in the magic of property parsing here.

Comment: each with the same properties? Or some with some of the properties and some with others?

Comment: you can remove this `@Qualifier("Bar Plugin Properties")` spring creates bean based on class names and anyhow you have two different classes

Comment: The problem might be `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "plugins.foo-plugin")` remove the `-` Spring uses some relaxed rules for binding properties with field names

Comment: @just each plugin can have N properties of its own

Comment: Tbh what I would do is make multiple properties files. If it is just one, I'd create some parser that creates multiple from one dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="plugins")
public class FooBarProperties{
    @Value("${FooPlugin.enabled}")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Value("${FooPlugin.amount}")
    private Integer amount;

    @Value("${BarPlugin.enabled}")
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

If you want seperate class just move that bar plugin to its own pojo

When you need the properties just autowire your class to inject the values
ie.

```
public void someFooBar() {
  @Autowired
  private FooBarProperties foobarProp;

...
}
```